# Android Facebook "me" request is very, very slow

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have basically copy/pasted this code from the Facebook API tutorials but when I run it, it can take upwards of 45(!) seconds to call onCompleted() which is obviously totally unacceptable. It has been this way for weeks and I have been putting it off but now I need to fix it. If anyone has any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong please help!

Edit: So after some more investigation it turns out that the time this takes can vary wildly. I have had it take over a minute and I have had it take less than 10 seconds. It seems to take less and less time the more I run it which could just be a fluke. I also updated to the latest Facebook SDK but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
 Session.openActiveSession( this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            if( session != null && session.isOpened() )
            {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest( session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            // callback after Graph API response with user object

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                            {
                                 // 30 - 45 seconds to get here!
                            }
                        }
                        );
                Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you running it on emulator?

Comment: No this is on an HTC Rezound so I can't blame the emulator :/

Comment: Test it with emulator and let me know.

Comment: Sorry took me a while to get back to this. As expected though the emulator is also taking way, way to long to get the onCompleted callback. I am really at a loss on this. If you have any other ideas I'm all ears.